# Символ "?" на странице ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, кодировка

Уже много лет у меня в сервисе встречается сопрадический баг -
на странице отображает символ знака вопроса "?" (Начало воспроизводится на MVC3 потом на MVC4 теперь и на MVC5) примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нет связи ни с браузерами, ни с кодировками и какой-либо систематики воспроизведения, после обновления страницы символ либо пропадает любо появляется в другом месте. Воспроизводится у многих пользователей в разных местах.

А теперь самое вкусное. Сегодня обновил Edge и открылась страница Microdoft.com:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая проблема у всех, получается? Или все таки есть механизмы решения этой проблемы? Хотя бы понимание природы явления (стабильное воспроизведение)?

Comment: Угу, я помню такое обсуждение: [По следам исчезнувших букв](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/cf540339-edbe-4a94-84e2-197844424ec2/-?forum=msdnfeedbackru). А воз и ныне там...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прям как детектив :)